# Compare two trees

Tags: perl

I have a huge tree (folder structure).
I made a csv export of this tree to be able to make changes to it.
After the changes are made i have to merge the changes back to my original tree.

I tried Text::Diff and XML::Diff.
XML::Diff doesn't work. It produces a different structure in the end. It has a bug and i am not able to find.
Text::Diff creates a patch file which is kind of hard to understand but is currently my best bet.

INFO: I need to understand each step in the "diff" to be able to apply it back to my original tree. A solution which gives me just the end result, without explaining each step is useless for me.

Comment: A depth first search and compare it line by line

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Text::Patch](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Patch) to apply the differences produced by [Text::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Diff).  These modules are modeled after the Unix/Linux `diff` and `patch` utilities --- the later originally written by Larry Wall himself.